# Django official tutorial models part4

Tags: python, django, forms, web, model

I'm following djangoproject official tutorials in part 4 it use `question.choice_set` Statment I don't know what is mean `choice_set` can anyone help me?

Can I use question.Objects for example instead of `question.choice_set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modelname_set` is default attribute name by which you can access reverse related objects . So in your you have model something like:

```
class Question(Model):
    ...

class Choice(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    ...
```

So if you want to get all choices related to specific question you can use followng syntax:

```
question.choice_set.all()
```

You can change attribute name to something more human readable using [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument:

```
class Choice(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices')
```

In this case you can now use `question.choices.all()` to get question's choices.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a `ForeignKey` from `Choice` to `Question`, like:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then Django **automatically creates an opposite relation**. By default, the name of the relation is `nameofmodel_set`.

Since there can be multiple `Choice` objects that map on the *same* `Question`, this is a set (a set that can contain zero, one, or more objects).

So by using `somequestion.choice_set`, you get an `ObjectManager` that deals with all the `Choice` objects for a *specific* `Question` instance (here the `somequestion`).

You can then for example `.filter(..)` on that set, or `.update(..)` or write custom ORM queries. So for example `somequestion.choice_set.all()` will give you *all* the related `Choice`s.

Sometimes the name of this reverse relation is not very nice, in that case, you can use the `reated_name` parameter, to give it another name, like:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='options')
```

In case you do not want such reverse relation (for example because it would result in a lot of confusion), then you can use a `'+'` as `related_name`:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    # no opposite relation
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='+')
```